# Need to fix height and width of select2 multiple-select search box

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

As and when I keep selecting multiple options in a select2 element, the text-area displaying the current selections keeps expanding, like the below:

[image]

I tried fix height of classes like `select2-selection` and `select2-container`. That did not help me. I ended up with something like the below.

[image: Unsuccessful attempt]

My requirement - I want to fix the height and width of the text area and all the options must be rendered within it. (Since, this will be part of a small pop-up and there are size restrictions).

Comment: Could you please provide your question with test example

Comment: Point taken - I will use jsfiddle the next time I post a question. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This turned out to be fairly simple. There was a span element of class `select2-selection--multiple` as the parent of the `li`s. All I had to do was add `overflow-y: auto` and that did the trick. I was not aware of this property.

My select2 combobox, now, looks like the below.

[image]

For my further reading - [overflow-y description in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Comment: is it possible to just comma-separated values instead of a scroll bar with close sign selected names? I mean after selection of 2 or 3 name it will change to like 3 option selected. i.e. just number of option selected in search box of select2.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.