# How to fix the height and width of a multiple select

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i keep selecting multiple options in a select element, the area displaying the current selection and it keeps expanding like the image below:

[image]

The thing I want to be is I want the select element be fix when selecting multiple options. Just like the example below:

[image]

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345248/need-to-fix-height-and-width-of-select2-multiple-select-search-box) but I don´t get how he made it.

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<select data-placeholder="Choose Username" multiple class="chosen-select" name="selectLDAP" id="selectLDAP" onchange='a()'>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value='option1'>option1</option>
    <option value='option2'>option2</option>
    <option value='option3'>option3</option>
    <option value='option4'>option4</option>
    <option value='option5'>option5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not standard `<select multiple>`, it uses some kind of plugin. Be clear please.

Comment: The linked question is using the Select2 jQuery plugin. Are you using the same?

Comment: Can please post your code here???

Comment: i think we are not using the same.

Comment: i edited the question so you may see my current code

Comment: Thank you. Tried to add that exact code to codepen, but I can't reproduce your problem (looks completely different). I would love to play around with it - if you could create a codepen (or similar) that clearly reproduces the problem...

Comment: @DavidTanzer i dont have idea on codepen. i´m sorry

Comment: Please also include in the question the exact call to `$( .... ).select2( .... )` that is in your code.

Comment: @Newbie just saw that "Run Code Snipped" reproduces your problem.

Comment: I saw the example of `select2 jQuery`. But i am looking like this`<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>` that fits with `select2`.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, you can add a height to the select component itself, but then you also have to define "overflow-y: auto" to get the scroll bars (and not just overflowing elements).

The real problem here is figuring out which element to style. jQuery does not leave your select as you wrote it - It renders something different:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" title="" id="selectLDAP_chosen" style="width: 70px;">
  <ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-choice"><span>option1</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a></li><li class="search-field">
      <input class="chosen-search-input" autocomplete="off" value="Choose Username" style="width: 25px;" type="text">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find that out by running the code snippet from your question and then using the development tools of your browser.

Again, in the development tools, you can try to find out which component is actually rendering the list and play around with the CSS properties to make it behave like you want.

You will find out that the  renders the list you want to style, so the following CSS should work:

```
.chosen-choices {
    height: 80px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Should do it. Your can use the developer tools of your browser to play around with the values before writing the actual CSS file.

Comment: It still expanding when i am selecting options. Thanks

Comment: Just tried again, if I edit the properties on the ul with class "chosen-choices" in the devtools, it works for me. I'm updating the answer with the correct CSS class. Sorry, my mistake ;)

Comment: Strange, but all I have is the "Run Code Snippet" from your answer, and when I add the properties there on the UL, it works. Maybe they are overwritten by some other CSS? Try adding !important to them to find out (or just edit the props in the dev tools). If this works, then you have another problem: Finding out which CSS file overwrites those properties. You should be able to find that out in the dev tools too, though: In firefox, there is "Computed Styles" and it tells you the CSS file the property comes from.

Comment: Yeah its strange. I left remain the select element but still not working

Comment: @Newbie tell me if I can do anything else help you - Or when you figured out the problem...

Comment: i still figuring out the problem. I saw the select2 jQuery but i dont have the link to connect the function like this: `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Comment: you using ul tag? how? I´m using simple select element

Comment: So, when I do "Run Code Snippet" with your code and open the dev tools of my browser (the only way I can debug your problem), I see that jQuery removes the select and renders (after choosing an option, among other things)

A ```<div class="chosen-container...``` and inside that an ```<ul class="chosen-choices">```. When I style that ul, things work for me.

Can you check in your browser's devtools that it renders the same in your production code?
If yes, try to manually style the ul.
If that works, try my CSS (maybe with !important).

And please tell my the results ;)

Comment: can u show me your code? have no idea with `<div class="chosen-container...` and the `<ul class="chosen-choices">`

Comment: Click the "run code snippet" button on the code in your question, choose one of the options in the rendered select, right-click and then choose "Inspect" in that menu (or whatever menu item will open the dev tools of your browser). Then you will see what jQuery **actually** renders (a div containing a ul and other stuff, at least in Firefox on Windows) and you can debug from there.

Comment: Also in edge on windows, by the way.

Comment: I see... but even i assign the css on chose-container, it still not working. This is so hard :(

Comment: Yes, I fell into that trap too. That's why I changed my answer to style ".chosen-choices" with CSS. But before you do that, try to manually set the properties with your development tools. If that works, you know you are styling the right component using the right properties. Then edit the CSS. If it works, good. If not, try to find out who/what is overwriting your properties. You can again see this in the development tools of your browser.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on our discussion. If it helped you troubleshoot this problem, please upvote it and accept it ;) If you need further help, I am here...

Comment: I tried to edit on the dev tool you saying. Its working there but when i apply on my css its not :(

Comment: Did you try ```!important``` in your CSS? Like: ```overflow-y: auto !important;```? Also, what value do the two CSS properties have in your rendered code, and where (from which CSS file) does that value come from (the dev tools will tell you that)?
Ultimately, you should not use ```!important```, but adding it temproarily here might help you to debug this problem.

Comment: `.chosen-choices{
   height: 80px;
   width: 150px;
   overflow-y:auto !important;
 }` here is the css that not working. And the dev tool didn´t tell where the value came from

Comment: which browser are you using? when you click on the UL, you should see all values of CSS properties, and the class of the element. Right now, I guess that eigher some other CSS overwrites the property, or that the class name is different in your production code.

Comment: OK, then click on the ul in the inspector, and you should see all CSS properties somewhere (I think the default is on the right side next to the html code, but I might be wrong). There, check if the properties from your CSS actually ended up at that element. If not, find out why (wrong class name?). If yes, and they were overwritten by some other CSS, find out why (wrong loading order?)